# Tensorflow to learn an input dependent and an input independent variable

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

i am trying to implement a physics informed network for equation discovery of the burger's equation (https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.10561). This consists of 2 predictions. The prediction of the velocity of the fluid which is dependent on the position and time point (which are the inputs) and on a diffusion coefficient nu, which is common throughout all of the profile.

I set up a network like so

```
def neural_network (train): 
inp_1 = Input(shape=(train.shape[1],))  #setting the size of the input layer
initial = 'he_uniform'
x = Dense(20,kernel_initializer= initial, activation = 'tanh', bias_initializer=initial)(inp_1)
x = Dense(20,kernel_initializer= initial, activation = 'tanh', bias_initializer=initial)(x)
x = Dense(20,kernel_initializer= initial, activation = 'tanh', bias_initializer=initial)(x)
x = Dense(20,kernel_initializer= initial,  activation = 'tanh',bias_initializer=initial)(x)
x = Dense(20,kernel_initializer= initial,  activation = 'tanh',bias_initializer=initial)(x)
x = Dense(20,kernel_initializer= initial,  activation = 'tanh',bias_initializer=initial)(x)

x = Dense(1,kernel_initializer= initial,  activation = 'tanh',bias_initializer=initial)(x)


nu = tf.Variable([[1.]], trainable = True, shape=((1,1)))
nu= Dense(1,kernel_initializer= initial,  activation = 'tanh',bias_initializer=initial)(nu)


out = tf.concat([x, nu], 1)

return Model(inputs=inp_1, outputs=out)


model = Sequential()

model = neural_network(xt_train)

model.summary()
```

and then tried to evaluate my expression on some sample ready code :

```
def residualValOfPDE(xt, nu):
    x = xt[:, 0:1] # x coordinate
    t = xt[:, 1:2] # t coordinate
    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
        
        tape.watch(x) 
        tape.watch(t)
        
        u, nu  = model( tf.stack([x[:, 0], t[:, 0]], axis=1) )[0]        
        u_x = tape.gradient(u, x)   
        
    u_t  = tape.gradient(u, t)        
    u_xx = tape.gradient(u_x, x)

    return u_t + u*u_x - nu*u_xx
```

Where xt_f contains the positions and times as columns and different points as rows.
Now, when i try to evaluate the expression for one point :

```
print( residualValOfPDE(xt_f[1:2,:], nu))
```

it works correctly. However when i try to pass multiple points in like:

```
print( residualValOfPDE(xt_f[1:3,:], nu))
```

I get the following error:

> InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 19     return u_t + u*u_x - nu*u_xx
> 20 #
> ---> 21 print( residualValOfPDE(xt_f[1:3,:], nu))  # calculate the residual value at each collection point
>
> in residualValOfPDE(xt, nu)
> 11         tape.watch(t)
> 12
> ---> 13         u, nu  = model( tf.stack([x[:, 0], t[:, 0]], axis=1) )[0]
> 14         u_x = tape.gradient(u, x)
> 15
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in
> error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
> 65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
> 66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.**traceback**)
> ---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
> 68     finally:
> 69       del filtered_tb
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py
> in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)    7105 def
> raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name):    7106   e.message += (" name: " +
> name if name is not None else "")
> -> 7107   raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access    7108     7109
>
> InvalidArgumentError: Exception encountered when calling layer
> "tf.concat_28" (type TFOpLambda).
>
> ConcatOp : Dimensions of inputs should match: shape[0] = [2,1] vs.
> shape[1] = [1,1] [Op:ConcatV2] name: concat
>
> Call arguments received:   • values=['tf.Tensor(shape=(2, 1),
> dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(1, 1), dtype=float32)']   • axis=1
> • name=concat

Any ideas how to solve it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the shape of `xt_f` and `nu`?

Comment: xtf_f has (10000, 2) and nu should have shape 1

Comment: I changed the code for nu to have the shape of xt_f and the same value throughout but then i get

 OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.

Comment: apologies, it was a type, now corrected

Comment: hmmm, weird. I get the shape () for nu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating the `nu` variable with a hard-coded batch size of 1. That is why it is only working with a sample size of 1 and no more. It is hard to say what you want to do, but you can try something like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

class NuLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

  def __init__(self, batch_dim, initial='he_uniform'):
    super(NuLayer, self).__init__()
    self.batch_dim = batch_dim

  def build(self, input_shape):
    self.nu = tf.Variable(initial_value = tf.ones((self.batch_dim,1)), trainable = True)

  def call(self, inputs):
    return self.nu

inp_1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(2,))  #setting the size of the input layer
initial = 'he_uniform'
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(20,kernel_initializer= initial, activation = 'tanh', bias_initializer=initial)(inp_1)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(20,kernel_initializer= initial, activation = 'tanh', bias_initializer=initial)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(20,kernel_initializer= initial, activation = 'tanh', bias_initializer=initial)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(20,kernel_initializer= initial, activation = 'tanh',bias_initializer=initial)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(20,kernel_initializer= initial, activation = 'tanh',bias_initializer=initial)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(20,kernel_initializer= initial, activation = 'tanh',bias_initializer=initial)(x)

x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,kernel_initializer= initial,  activation = 'tanh',bias_initializer=initial)(x)

nu = NuLayer(batch_dim=4)
nu = nu(inp_1)
out = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([x, nu])
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inp_1, outputs=out)

def residualValOfPDE(xt):
    
    x = xt[:, 0:1] # x coordinate
    t = xt[:, 1:2] # t coordinate
    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
        
        tape.watch(x) 
        tape.watch(t)
        u, nu  = model(tf.stack([x[:, 0], t[:, 0]], axis=1) )[0]        
        u_x = tape.gradient(u, x)   
        
    u_t  = tape.gradient(u, t)        
    u_xx = tape.gradient(u_x, x)

    return u_t + u*u_x - nu*u_xx

xt_f = tf.random.normal((10000, 2))

print( residualValOfPDE(xt_f[1:3,:]))
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[[0.5751909]
 [0.       ]], shape=(2, 1), dtype=float32)
```

If you want to examine a different batch size, then change the batch size in the `Input` layer:

```
nu = NuLayer(batch_dim=4)
print( residualValOfPDE(xt_f[1:5,:]))
```

```
[[-0.51205623]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]], shape=(4, 1), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: That is very close to what i want. A few questions:
1) Is it possible to have the batch size dynamically?
2) Is it possible to just return self.nu and have it be trainable?

Comment: Question 1: You would have to rearrange your whole model. Currently, no. Question 2: Yes. Check updated answer.

Comment: Thank you! I just stacked the nu rather than have the batch size dynamically and it seems to work. Sadly, it doesnt quite train yet but i ll keep poking and see what comes out :-D